# mat autocomplete is too slow while loading large data

Tags: html, angular, autocomplete, mat-autocomplete

I am using mat autocomplete https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api in my angular project. while loading large data with 25k items. the performance gets low. it is too slow to search and suggest autocomplete. how to increase the performance of this?

Comment: load less data... and only the necessary data. don't load entire objects if you only need a name, and don't load everything if you only need items that start with 'a' or something...

Comment: Can you set up a working stackblitz example (even with only a dozen example items)? Your question is far to abstract to think about an appropriate answer. Normally, your server api should care about indexing, sorting and caching and push only few data to the Angular client, which in turn has to care about debounceTime, only necessary api http calls and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to load less data to your autocomplete . But if you really need to display/search this many items. The solution to your problem is virtual scroll.https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview
Because the filter function  depending on the filter function you are using  the most time is used by repainting it.
Or a simpler solution but uses a bit more resource than virtual scroll .
https://medium.com/better-programming/improving-angular-ngfor-performance-through-trackby-ae4cf943b878

Comment: Thanks for your answer brother. cdk virtual scroll solved my problem.

Answer (score 22):

I was in the same situation and my solution was to limit the list to first N results. So the code looks like this:

**component.html**

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="name">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredItems" [value]="item">
        {{item.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

**component.ts**

```
this.filteredItems = this.items.filter(...some.filtering here...).slice(0, 10);
```

You will be filtering all items, but showing only first 10 matching. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

If data is huge in autocomplete then performance low, I have resolved the same issue using *cdkVirtualFor replaces *ngFor inside autocomplete.

please find references below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/autocomplete-with-virtual-scroll?file=app%2Fcdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.ts

Comment: Consider editing your answer to include the applicable code section from the link reference. Code sections can be searched.

Comment: your solution was just perfect for my use case, thanks